# how to select a specific div smartly without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-frontend

currently I am building a table which includes two same checkbox group which needs to be checked automatically when another was checked, below is the jquery script I am using, how can I use a smarted way to handle this function instead of using millions of ID like I do at present?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#GMSC01BOX-1").change(function() {
    $("#GMSC01BOX-2").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#GMSC01BOX-2").change(function() {
    $("#GMSC01BOX-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#GMSC02BOX-1").change(function() {
    $("#GMSC02BOX-2").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#GMSC02BOX-2").change(function() {
    $("#GMSC02BOX-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#VMSC01BOX-1").change(function() {
    $("#VMSC01BOX-2").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#VMSC01BOX-2").change(function() {
    $("#VMSC01BOX-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#VMSC02BOX-1").change(function() {
    $("#VMSC02BOX-2").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#VMSC02BOX-2").change(function() {
    $("#VMSC02BOX-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#GMGW01BOX-1").change(function() {
    $("#GMGW01BOX-2").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("#GMGW01BOX-2").change(function() {
    $("#GMGW01BOX-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CS-popup" class="popup-windows ">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" id="GMSC01BOX-1">GMSC01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC02" id="GMSC02BOX-1">GMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC01" id="VMSC01BOX-1">VMSC01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC02" id="VMSC02BOX-1">VMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW01" id="GMGW01BOX-1">GMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW02" id="GMGW02BOX-1">GMGW02
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW01" id="VMGW01BOX-1">VMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW02" id="VMGW02BOX-1">VMGW02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS01" id="SPS01BOX-1">SPS01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS02" id="SPS02BOX-1">SPS02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS01" id="HSS01BOX-1">HSS01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS02" id="HSS02BOX-1">HSS02
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" id="GMSC01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne016" type="checkbox" id="GMSC02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne017" type="checkbox" id="VMSC01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne018" type="checkbox" id="VMSC02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne019" type="checkbox" id="GMGW01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne020" type="checkbox" id="GMGW02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne021" type="checkbox" id="VMGW01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne022" type="checkbox" id="VMGW02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne023" type="checkbox" id="SPS01BOX-2">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmE/1127/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

i added a data-selector attribute to every checkbox and it have same value for pairs

*if we use  class then there is a chance of style overriding*

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
  var selector = $(this).data('selector');
  $('[data-selector="'+selector +'"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CS-popup" class="popup-windows ">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" data-selector ="GMSC01BOX-1" >GMSC01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC02" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1">GMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC01" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1">VMSC01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC02" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1">VMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW01" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1">GMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW02" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1">GMGW02
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW01" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1">VMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW02" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1">VMGW02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS01" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1">SPS01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS02" data-selector="SPS02BOX-1">SPS02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS01" data-selector="HSS01BOX-1">HSS01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS02" data-selector="HSS02BOX-1">HSS02
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" data-selector ="GMSC01BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne016" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne017" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne018" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne019" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1">
  </TD1
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne020" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne021" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne022" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne023" type="checkbox" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Between the related group of check box, the only matching part is the first 6 digits of `id`. You can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to check whether the matching `id` part [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) any other checkbox or not:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){
    var idMachedPart = this.id.substring(0,6);
    var status = this.checked;
    $('[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
      if(this.id.startsWith(idMachedPart))
        $(this).prop('checked', status);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CS-popup" class="popup-windows ">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" id="GMSC01BOX-1">GMSC01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC02" id="GMSC02BOX-1">GMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC01" id="VMSC01BOX-1">VMSC01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC02" id="VMSC02BOX-1">VMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW01" id="GMGW01BOX-1">GMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW02" id="GMGW02BOX-1">GMGW02
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW01" id="VMGW01BOX-1">VMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW02" id="VMGW02BOX-1">VMGW02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS01" id="SPS01BOX-1">SPS01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS02" id="SPS02BOX-1">SPS02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS01" id="HSS01BOX-1">HSS01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="HSS02" id="HSS02BOX-1">HSS02
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" id="GMSC01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne016" type="checkbox" id="GMSC02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne017" type="checkbox" id="VMSC01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne018" type="checkbox" id="VMSC02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne019" type="checkbox" id="GMGW01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne020" type="checkbox" id="GMGW02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne021" type="checkbox" id="VMGW01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne022" type="checkbox" id="VMGW02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne023" type="checkbox" id="SPS01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne024" type="checkbox" id="SPS02BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne025" type="checkbox" id="HSS01BOX-2">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne026" type="checkbox" id="HSS02BOX-2">
  </TD>
</div>
</div>
```

Please Note: You should look your HTML. To me this not entirely valid.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways here

First: The repetitive way
Use a class and toggle each checkbox with the same class

```
  $(".box-1").change(function() {
    $(".box-1").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });

  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" class="box-1">GMSC01

  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" id="GMSC01BOX-2" class="box-1">
  </TD>
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/sktnye6p/2/

My favorite way and also dynamic and for reusability
I'll use the data- attribute

Declare a class that will be use for each checkbox

```
  $(".box").change(function() {
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    let target = $(document).find("[data-index='" + index + "']"); 
    $(target).prop("checked", this.checked);
  });



<input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" class="box" data-index="1">GMSC01
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" class="box" data-index="1">
  </TD>
```

Fiddle here :  http://jsfiddle.net/sLzgxty0/4/